# Preventing from using my REST APIs from outside my own client JS app

Tags: security, authentication, architecture, facebook-access-token

I built an AngularJS application calling some REST API's belonging to my own backend (using Play! 2.2).

I'm using Facebook OAuth client in order to authenticate my users.
As being a **Javascript App**, my **Facebook App Token** cannot be "hidden".

Thus, anybody who picked up the Facebook App Token, by just reading the Javascript code could grab a user access token in a "legally" way and therefore use my REST API's.

How could I prevent it?
What is the best practice?

One way would be, I think, to use the server side Facebook's OAuth mechanism, rather than the Facebook Javascript SDK.
In this case, the Facebook app secret would be stored on my server and unreachable from the outside.

But as being a Single Page Application on client-side, I really want to avoid page redirection and benefit of the "popup" feature that comes with Facebook Javascript SDK.

Comment: One way would be to configure the authorized domain in the facebook app settings (myDomain.com), in order to make this domain having the exclusivity of authentication. Would it be enough secure?

Comment: one interesting post that could really be an answer :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253272/vulnerability-with-facebook-token-hijacking.  Explaining in the given answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do.

Using the server side ("code") OAuth flow for facebook auth is much more secure. You can still avoid redirects by opening your own popup to initiate the login sequence, similar to what the Facebook JS does (only it goes to your server first).

Enabling HTTPS on your application is usually a good practice...

And if you're worried about cross site forgeries you can implement something like an anti forgery state token. See http://blog.codinghorror.com/preventing-csrf-and-xsrf-attacks/ and also google's instructions here https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#createxsrftoken .

Comment: It seems that even with Facebook Javascript SDK, we can end up with a pretty strong security by allowing the right tokens origin (domain) in the app settings, and by checking the access token with the `Debug tool` before each use.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security/

Comment: Right, but if your application is not using HTTPS I wouldn't recommend passing user tokens around.