# Can I safely authenticate a Facebook user with just Facebook Signed Request?

Tags: facebook, authentication, twitter, oauth

I want to enable my users to associate their user account with a Facebook or Twitter and allow them to login on my server with their Facebook/Twitter account instead of using the classic username/password. Basically the same idea as the login in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login-add).

My current approach for Facebook: 
The client application will perform OAuth and then use their Facebook id to login on my server. Based on this Facebook id, the server will lookup the associated user account and perform login without asking for username/pasword.  However just relying on the Facebook id to login is not very safe, as that is the same as using only a username to login instead of username & password.

So to make sure the Facebook id is authentic, the client application will also provide a FBSR (Facebook Signed Request, see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/using-login-with-games/#checklogin) with the login request.
The server will check two things with this FBSR:

1. The Facebook id in the request must be the same as the one hidden in the FBSR
2. Server will recalculate the signature part via the Facebook secret key. This must match with the signature in the FBSR .

Normally the server should perform a check with the Facebook server with the oauth_token to be 100% sure of the users identity. However I need skip this in order to avoid dependency to Facebook server on our server.

I have 2 questions:

1)  Is this above approach good enough? Can it be improved (without server-to-server communication)?

2)  I want to do the same with a Twitter account, but the their signed request is different then Facebook. It seems the Twitter user id is embedded in the oauth_token, so my approach may work with a little tweak, but I am not sure whether the user id is always part of the oauth_token and cannot get this confirmed after searching the internet.

Comment: I think you should still check that the access token (oauth_token) you receive is actually for your application, if your app secret gets leaked then anyone can generate a FBSR and used hijaked tokens. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security#tokenhijacking http://stackoverflow.com/a/21257380/2779152

Comment: Token hijacking isn't really an issue here as we don't use the access token (no actual server-to-server communication). Instead we check whether the FBSR is valid and the Facebook id in it. Leaking of the app secret is a weak point indeed, but since the client doesn't have the app secret it shouldn't be a big issue.

Comment: Cool, just make sure you don't accidentally push it to GitHub like [all these people](https://github.com/search?q=%22facebook_app_secret+%3D+%27%22&type=Code&ref=searchresults)

Answer (score 1):

I think that your approach is good enough and don't see any way to avoid server-to-server communication with a signed request. Bear in mind that, with Facebook Graph Api Version 2, in order to protect the privacy of the user, Facebook will send out not the real user id, but one generated for apps. It will also be possible to enable anonymous login.

I am not sure of what you're trying to do with Twitter, and why you compare the APIs (they're quite different). The [Twitter login](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/sign-twitter), also know as Sign in with Twitter, used for any website or mobile app, should work for you too.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up Facebook Graph Api version 2 and anonymous login which I haven't scoped in my approach, but important to consider nonetheless.

Regarding Twitter, the basic idea is to allow someone to authenticate on my server with Twitter login, just like what I have explained in my approach for Facebook. 
Both [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request) and Facebook support OAuth and Signed Request, so that is why I compare the 2 API which are indeed quite different.

Comment: As explained, my approach is basically allowing my users to login with just a user id from Facebook or Twitter. The only security measure I take, to prevent people tampering the login request, is by doing the Signed Request check on my server.