# How to Implement facebook login/registration in a REST web application

Tags: php, facebook, api

I'm making a REST accessible web application to support a mobile application.
The application is made in PHP (and MySQL as backend database).
Some REST calls are public, some others are private.
I've already implemented my login/registration service but I would to implement facebook login/registration.
How can I do it? Are there some examples?
I suppose I should save facebook login token and pass it thought every call (as like user+md5pass) and check it at facebook server every time from my web app.
Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I am doing something similar on our server, please see my approach on: [Can I safely authenticate a Facebook user with just Facebook Signed Request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160384/allow-users-to-login-on-web-server-using-facebook-twitter).

However as stated in my approach we don't do a server-to-server check with the Facebook Server. To avoid dependency on the response from Facebook we only do a check on the signature in the "signed request", which should be safe enough in my opinion.

Facebook have some an php example explained here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/using-login-with-games/#checklogin